# ¿Cómo ver el contenido de un script en R?

Tags: r, programación-funcional

Como saben, cuando uno llama `source("path_script")` en R podemos traer un script a nuestra sesión de trabajo y utilizar las funciones y comandos que en él se encuentren. Sin embargo, ¿hay alguna forma de saber exactamente qué contiene dicho script? Me refiero algo así como una especie de llamado a `dir` de consola. Es decir, pienso en algo como esto:

```
source("path_script")
dir ("nombre_script")
##Se despliega contenido del script
```

Cualquier comentario u orientación, la agradeceré mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ver el contenido completo de una script R no conozco nada específico, pero un script no deja de ser un archivo de texto, por lo que podrías terminar usando `readlines()`:

```
cat(readLines('prueba.R'), sep='\n')
```

Como `readlines()` nos entrega un vector, usamos `cat()` para concatenar todo en una sola cadena y así verlo mejor.

Por otro lado, si lo que buscas es solo ver los objetos que contiene un Script, normalmente funciones o variables, eso se ve luego de hacer el `source` del archivo, es decir luego que R evalúa el mismo, el comando `ls()` justamente listará los nuevos objetos cargados por el script. Suponiendo un script que llamaremos `prueba.R` como el siguiente:

```
prueba <- function(x) {
    cat(x)
}

variable_n <- c(1)
variable_c <- "hola"
```

Luego del `source('script.r')` podremos listar los nuevos objetos cargados al entorno actual con `ls()`

```
> ls()
[1] "prueba"     "variable_c" "variable_n"
```

Esto tiene un potencial problema, que es, que para ver los objetos de un script, ensuciamos el entorno actual (esta es una de las tantas ventajas de los paquetes), de hecho, puede ser problemático identificar los objetos si ya tenemos un entorno muy "cargado", además que eventualmente podríamos estar sobreescribiendo objetos que ya existieran en el entorno. Pero, podríamos crear un entorno específico dónde evaluar nuestro script, y de esta forma resolvemos los problemas antes mencionados, por ejemplo:

```
get_objects_from_source <- function(src) {

    new <- new.env(parent = .BaseNamespaceEnv)
    source(src, local=new)

    objs <- lapply(ls(envir=new),
                   function(x) {
                       o <- get(x, envir=new)
                       cbind(name=x, class=class(o))
                   })

    do.call(rbind.data.frame, objs)
}

get_objects_from_source('prueba.R')


        name     class
1     prueba  function
2 variable_c character
3 variable_n   numeric
```

La función es bien sencilla, lo primero que se hace es  crear un entorno nuevo con `new <- new.env(parent = .BaseNamespaceEnv)` y luego se carga el script en dicho entorno, mediante `source(src, local=new)`, una vez cargado el script, simplemente iteramos sobre los objetos mediante `lapply(ls(envir=new), ...)` y no quedamos con el nombre y la clase del objeto que luego retornaremos.

Comentarios:

- Podríamos evitar crear un nuevo entorno y utilizar el entorno privado o local de la función, pero siempre estará "intoxicado" con los objetos propios de la función.
- No debería haber inconvenientes con un script que solo contenga funciones o variables para incorporar al script actual que se esté ejecutando, pero si hay que considerar algunos inconvenientes con scripts que sean ejecutables:

  1. Estamos evaluando el código, es decir lo estamos ejecutando, cualquier salida, plot o demás se ejecutará y si tenemos algún problema lo trasladamos a nuestra función.
  2. La lectura de los objetos se hace una vez finalizada la ejecución, cualquier objeto que hubiera sido definido y eventualmente destruido, no se mostrará en la lista final.

Comment: Sigo insistiendo: ¿Hay algo que no seas capaz de resolver? Muchas gracias; tu función es ilustrativa y muy eficiente. Saludos.